# error installing laravel show routecollection.php line 161

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

i just installing laravel using this guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation
after installation, it always show error [image]
i've tried to update composer, clear-cache, clear-compiled, optimized, key-generate, serve on another port, and change permission of storage and bootstrap folder. I tried to install another version of laravel (5.1), still doesn't work. Please help me.
FYI : i'm using xampp with php 7.

Comment: What is your route?

Comment: does other php project run in your machine? and are you running php artisan serve in the cmd to load the project?

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari 
 
this is my route Route::get('/', function () {return view('welcome');}); it's a fresh install, i havent change anything

Comment: @Exprator yeah, another project is working although it's not laravel, and i'm running it on cmd

Comment: what url are you giving in the browser? and where is your laravel project folder and what is the name of it?

Comment: @Exprator localhost:8000/laravel, it's in htdocs/laravel

Comment: try this in your browser once localhost/laravel

Comment: it show the directory folder, because when i run serve, it will run on port 8000

Comment: Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');

put this in your routes.php

Answer (score 0):

Be ensure to enable mod_rewrite module in apache in xampp, you can do this by reading below post:

http://www.orchidbox.com/post.php?title=How_to_enable_mod_rewrite_module_in_apache_in_xampp_wamp

Then try again